# How do you get tsserver's response to the `geterr` command?

Tags: typescript

I tried the following command:

```
$ echo "{ \"seq\": 0, \"type\": \"request\", \"command\": \"geterr\", \"arguments\": { \"files\": [ \"/path/to/my/file/example.ts\" ], \"delay\": 0 } }" | ./node_modules/.bin/tsserver
```

and all I got as a response was

```
Content-Length: 77

{"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"requestCompleted","body":{"request_seq":0}}
```

How can I see the tsserver errors? I would like to use this (or possibly the `geterrForProject` command) to get a list of all the errors for my project.

For reference, my `example.ts` file looked like this:

```js
functioxn x(4) {
  console.log(1);
}
d
```

which contains errors on purpose. My editor shows the errors in this file properly.

Comment: The purpose of this was to get TS errors from a command line command. I found out that I can just use `npx tsc --noemit` to do this. It would still be nice to get an answer to this specific question, but for my actual development purposes, I have what I need now.